# How to add aspx page as a link in VSTS 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have two web application I want to add WebForm from one application as a link to other application. So only one physical copy will be in solution. But after deployment it will have different copies.

Comment: can you please add more detail? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I wanted to add same existing page from another project as a link in my project and I have found an answer. I should "Add existing Item" and open it "As a link" while browse.